# Can you run an Android Studio emulator inside hyper v Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, android, hyper-v, android-emulator

I have set up a VM through Hyper V in Windows. With this I open up and use Ubuntu. In this Ubuntu I am trying to create an Android Studio Emulator but I literally cannot start any of the emulators because all the images give this error:

> Your CPU does not support required features (VT-x or SVM)

My questions:

1. **What does this error mean?**
2. **How do I resolve it?**

Notes:

- Is it because I am trying to run an emulator (VM) inside an VM?
- Below that it says

  > We recommend these Google Play images because this device is compatible with Google Play`, does this mean anything?
- I am very new to Hyper-V, Ubuntu and Android Studio
- I don't have an abnormally weak laptop so I don't think it is hardware issues

Answer (score 1):

Installing a virtual device requires too much of your system resources and VT-x or SVM need the system to be able to have a minimum virtual memory; if that isn't present then the error will occur.

Android Studio needs to have at least  6GB of RAM and the emulator needs at least 2GB RAM to run smoothly (depending on the OS that you use - its API 28 "Android Q" requires 2GB). This is not including the virtual memory. the point is you can't (under normal circumstances) run an Android emulator inside another emulator as it requires excess resources.

You can still run it in Windows or Linux if you are not using a virtual device inside another virtual device.

Answer (score 1):

Your CPU does not support required features (VT-x or SVM)

Either your CPU doesn't support VT-x or it's disabled in BIOS. You can look up your CPU on Intel ARK portal, check if it supports virtualization extensions. If it does, find this feature in BIOS of your laptop.